# No "Final" option under Physics Properties > Cache > Type

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking, cache

My question is pretty simple. In all the tutorials I've watched at some point the instructor says to set the option `Physics Properties > Cache > Type` to `Final` but my only options are `Modular` `Replay` and `All`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I figured out a work around. So I just need to break it into several steps.

1. Check checkbox `Physics Properties > Fluid > Mesh`
2. Set `Physics Properties > Fluid > Cache > Type` to `Modular` and check `Is Resumable`
3. In `Physics Properties > Fluid > Settings` select `Bake Data` (after this process runs the button then changes to say `Free Data`
4. AFTER STEP 4 - In `Physics Properties > Fluid > Mesh` select `Bake Mesh` (after this process runs the button then changes to say `Free Mesh`)

[image]

[image]

[image]